# How to call my method

Tags: java, class, methods

I have been trying to call my timeTurn method, and every time I try, nothing happens except errors when I try to compile. I looked online and people kept saying to make classes and then call that method using (e.g. T.timeTurn), and still, it does not work. The error I'm getting says, "timeTurn cannot be resolved or is not a field". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
myFinch.setWheelVelocities(240,255,T.timeTurn);
myFinch.sleep(500);

static class T {

  public static Object timeTurn (int[] length) { 
    int minMillsecond = 1000; 
    int maxMillsecond = 3000; 
    int gap = 33; 
    for(int len : length)
      if (30 <= len && len <= 90) { 
        len += minMillsecond; 
        while(len < 3000) {
          len+=gap;
        } 
        System.out.println(len); 
      }
    return timeTurn(length); 
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Please verify your code's indentation as well as if each opening curly bracket and its own closing counterpart.

Comment: this is an endless recursion, once you call the method with a non-empty length[] it will endlessly call it self.

Comment: Where are you trying to call this method? In the main method of the class or where? Also, like @SteveL said, this is an infinite recursion.

Comment: I am calling it in my main. And thanks for letting me know, been doing this for the whole day and I cannot brain.

Comment: And what's your timeTurn method supossed to return? Now it returns nothing because it stucks in an infinite loop. Also you forgot to pass an int array when you call it from your main.

Comment: We can tell you, so far, exactly two technical problems. (You're not invoking timeTurn() with an int array argument, and it recurses infinitely.) But it looks to me as if there are other issues. Would you mind telling us, as an edit to the question, what exactly the method is supposed to be doing and what it's supposed to return?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the array parameter.

Try to use `myFinch.setWheelVelocities(240,255,T.timeTurn(new int[0]));` instead of `myFinch.setWheelVelocities(240,255,T.timeTurn);`.

I believe you have some array available to use.

Comment: You probably don't need the error if you think about what they're returning from the method. But this does answer the calling issue except passing an empty array won't be very interesting.

Comment: This should address OP's immediate compile error. The infinite recursion, of course, will raise its ugly head soon.

Comment: As I have written, I believe that there is an available array. Let's wait for updates.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm gonna have to rethink my method... Thank you trying to help and noticing that it's infinite.